# Get ELB name from inside EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ec2

I want to get the ELB name from inside the EC2 instance.

I can do a `aws elb describe-load-balancers` but this needs the ELB name as input.

I want do it reverse - I know the EC2 instance details from EC2 metadata and want to find the ELB name so that I can append to a file.

Comment: What do you mean by "the elb name"? Do you mean the name of the ELB that is being used to serve traffic to that specific EC2 instance? It is possible to serve traffic from multiple ELBs to the same EC2 instance, so you might get multiple results.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein "elb name" Name of ELB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `aws elb describe-load-balancers` doesn't need the elb name. It will list all the elbs you have. Then you can parse the output JSON and get which instances are attached to every ELB. I don't know if this is your case, but you can find which elb your instance is attached, and then grab the elb name.

Regards